# How to disable desktop notifications for colcon?

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 using ROS 2 Foxy. I have installed colcon using:

```
sudo apt install python3-colcon-common-extensions
```

It works fine, but I get desktop notifications when, for example, a build fails. I find the notifications extremely annoying. How can I disable them for colcon? I can't find an option to do that anywhere, and I don't want to disable notifications entirely.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356880/how-to-disable-desktop-notifications-for-colcon?/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2020-07-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the recommendation from this ticket: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-notification/issues/31#issuecomment-554213559

Since the `desktop_notification` event handler is provided by a specific extension it is possible to blacklist that specific extension using an environment variable:

```
COLCON_EXTENSION_BLACKLIST=colcon_core.event_handler.desktop_notification
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2020-07-10**:
That's perfect. Thanks.

**Comment by [jpace121](https://answers.ros.org/users/51025/jpace121/) on 2022-07-04**:
A quick update to Dirk's excellent answer:

Sometime between his answer and now the environment variable was renamed to `COLCON_EXTENSION_BLOCKLIST` so the proper incantation now is:

`COLCON_EXTENSION_BLOCKLIST=colcon_core.event_handler.desktop_notification`